# Construct $g(x)$ differentiable with certain properties given $f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

Given a measurable function $f:R \to [0,\infty)$

and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx=1$

given $a,b \in R$ and $b>a$ , $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure.

Can we construct a function $g(x)$ with the following properties:

1. It is differentiable everywhere
2. $\int_{c}^{d}(f(x)+g(x))dx \ge 0$  for all $c,d \in [a,b]$ with $d>c$
3. $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(f(x)+g(x))dx=1$
4. $g(a)=g(b)=0$
5. $g(x)$ is non trivial, that is $\mu(\{x \in R : |g(x) |>0\}) \neq 0$

Comment: Take $g\equiv 0$.

Comment: @Vahe the second condition doesn't hold for every such $f$ if $g = 0$

Comment: @Legolas131 it does, $f$ is nonnegative.

Comment: @Vahe you are right, I supposed to add not trivial solution as property no. 5

Comment: @Legolas131 yeah I supposed to add non trivial solution as  property no. 5

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer:

If $f$ is Riemann Integrable then $g(x)$ can be constructed as follows :

$$n,j \in N, a_1=a,a_{n+1}=b$$

$$\sum_{j=1}^{j=n}(a_{j+1}-a_j)=b-a$$

$r_j(x)=-{\frac {1}{x^2-a_j^2}}$

$q_j(x)=-{\frac {1}{a_{j+1}^2-x^2}}$

$s_j(x)=-{\frac {1}{2(x^2-a_j^2)}}$

$t_j(x)=-{\frac {1}{2(a_{j+1}^2-x^2)}}$

$$\psi_j(x) =e^{q_j(x)+r_j(x)} , \text{if $a_j< x< a_{j+1}$ }$$

$$\psi_j(x) =0  , \text{if $x$ $\notin (a_j,a_{j+1})$}$$

$$\phi_j(x) =e^{s_j(x)+t_j(x)} , \text{if $a_j< x< a_{j+1}$ }$$

$$\phi_j(x) =0  , \text{if $x$ $\notin (a_j,a_{j+1})$}$$

$$p_j=\min_{x \in [a_j,a_{j+1})} f(x)$$

because $f$ is Riemann integrable there is a partitioning such that there is some $j=k$ , such that $p_k(x) \neq 0$

let $$g(x)=-\sum_{j=1}^{j=n}p_j(x)\psi_j(x)+A\sum_{j=1}^{j=n}p_j(x)\phi_j(x)$$

$$\sum_{j=1}^{j=n}p_j(x)\psi_j(x) < \sum_{j=1}^{j=n}p_j(x)\phi_j(x)  \text{for $x \neq a_j$ }$$

Where $$A=\frac{\int_a^b\sum_{j=1}^{j=n}p_j(x)\psi_j(x)}{\int_a^b\sum_{j=1}^{j=n}p_j(x)\phi_j(x)}$$ and it follows $$1>A>0$$

Note $$f(x)-\sum_{j=1}^{j=n}p_j(x)\psi_j(x) \ge 0$$

$$f(x)-A\sum_{j=1}^{j=n}p_j(x)\phi_j(x) \ge 0$$

It is a simple exercise to see $g$ satisfy all the properties.

Remark :for $\epsilon \in (-1 ,1)$, $\epsilon g(x)$ also satisfy all the properties

writing $$w_{\epsilon}(x)=f(x)-\epsilon g(x)$$

$$\text{Each } w_{\epsilon}(x) \text{ can represent a probabilty distribution}$$